# Change seller name in Apple Store

Tags: app-store

Does anyone know how to change the developer name (or seller name) that appears in Apple Store? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorporate, contact Apple requesting a change to a company enrollment, and be ready to fax your incorporation papers to Apple if needed.  No other name changes seem to be permitted.